# Why is my code giving me an SQL error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My following SQL code is showing up an error. The error message that appears in phpMyAdmin is

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long = -6.52607, lat = 54.10046, reg = 'Rge info ere', info = 'general info here' at line 1

The long and lat work ok when i insert them directly using phpmyadmin but now when performing an sql query. The two fields are set as float. Ive tired them both with and without using signle quotes.

```
INSERT INTO events SET 
  name = 'Home Event', 
  url = 'home-event', 
  eventDate = '2013-06-29', 
  address1 = '18 Daly Park', 
  address2 = 'Silverbridge', 
  city = 'Newry', 
  county = 'Down', 
  postcode = 'BT35 9PJ', 
  long = -6.52607, 
  lat = 54.10046, 
  reg = 'Rge info ere', 
  info = 'general info here', 
  contact = 'contact me', 
  image = ''
```

Comment: `Long` is a reserved word. You'll need to quote it in backticks; or rename the column to something else.

Comment: But how come it works ok using the phpMyAdmin interface?

Comment: @PierceMcGeough phpMyAdmin knows about that problem and puts these ` around it.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense @glglgl. I thought it was a keyword problem but because it was working in phpMyAdmin that confused me

Comment: @PierceMcGeough It's cool SQL is probably one of the most picky languages when it comes to syntax and it's error messages are not always very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

you are using a mysql reserved keyword wich is `long`, you will need to escape it in the query with backtick to let it understand it is a `column name`

```
`long` = -6.52607,
```

Have a look at [**documentation here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

As side notes about `mysql reserved keyword` I would add that you can avoid escaping them by giving a table alias and then using column name with `alias.` before it. Actually `INSERT` query doesn't support table alias so you cannot use in this specific situation.

Answer (score 5):

If you tried to google the error message, `LONG` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

You have two choices to make it working,

One, wrap the column name with backtick,

```
`long` = -6.52607
```

or two, change the column name so error won't return back again.

You can find here the list of all keywords: [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 3):

long is a keyword you should get into the practice of escaping and quoting your text with SQL

change long to `long`

```
`long` = -6.52607,
```